# Using tensordot to batch matrix multiplies

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

If I want to compute the matrix-matrix product `a*b`, I would do `a@b` or `np.dot(a,b)`

```
a = np.random.rand(2,2)
b = np.random.rand(*a.shape)
c = a@b
c.shape
>>> (2,2)
```

In general, I can use tensordot to do the same:

```
c = np.tensordot(a,b,1)
c.shape
>>> 2,2
```

However, if I add a dimension to a and b, I no longer get the result I'd like (another 2,2,3 array):

```
a = np.random.rand(2,2,3)
b = np.random.rand(*a.shape)
c = np.tensordot(a,b,1)
c.shape
>>> ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
```

Any permutation of axes I try, even the hideous `b,axes=((0,1),(0,1))`, results in either not the right output shape, or an error because the calculation cannot be done.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I was under the impression it would be straightforward with tensordot, but it seems not...

Comment: `tensordot` does not good for batches.  Use `matmul/@` or `einsum`

Comment: Any guidance on _how_ to make those functions do what I'm after?

Comment: Which dimension is the batch, and which are being `dotted`?

Comment: Suppose I want the matrix-matrix product of the first two dimensions (0 and 1), and any other dims are to be preserved.  If the others need to be collapsed via a reshape and then re-expanded, that's ok.

Comment: `matmul` docs should make it clear the the first (of 3) is the batch.  The dot rules apply to the last 2.  `einsum` is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me (2, 2, 3) output. But please note I never did 3d dot products before, so check if those output values are correct:

```
output = np.matmul(a,b, axes=[(0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 1)])
print(output.shape)
```

```
(2, 2, 3)
```